# Effective graph interpretation C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, graph

i have this problem:
i have a graph with nodes, whose value is between 1 and 200M. And the graph has 200M nodes  and not more than 300M transitions. Transitions are with char symbols (between 'a' and 'z')
so I keep them all in this:
          map < char, int >  transitions[200000000];
but it is very cost innefective.
in transitions[i] i is the unique value of the state, and transitions[i][c], where c is a char symbol, is the state we go to from "i" with the char "c"
However if i have 8M states, it takes 1.6gb ram. And i have a limit of 8 gb ram for this one to work with 200M nodes.
Could you give me an advice for something more effective? I also have 2 x int arrays with 200 million size. Which should also fit in these 8gb ram. It takes like 1.6gb ram :)

Comment: Checkout the boost graph library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems, using

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, char>, int>> edges;
```

would be more effective: the entry `((f, x), t)` would represent the transition from node `f` to node `t` with symbol `z`. You'd keep this vector sorted and locate the transitions using `std::lower_bound(edges.begin(), edges.end(), predicate)` with a suitable predicate. The memory footprint would probably be roughly `3 * sizeof(int) * e` where `e` is the number of edges.

Comment: @Diemtar You mean `e` is the number of edges by the end, correct?

Comment: @Xephon: er, yes - had first used `n` but that's normally used for nodes... Corrected! Thanks!